# Using the return value of "scanf()" to check for end of file

Tags: c, file, scanf

I was searching the net on how to use return value of scanf to check the end of file!
I found the following code.But i am having difficulty in understanding?

How is this method working?

What does the '~' operator signify?

```
while(~scanf("%d",&n)) { 
  /* Your solution */
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't we be using `fscanf()` instead to read from files?`scanf()` reads data exclusively from `stdin` eh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a horrible way to check if a value is different from -1. `~x` returns the bitwise negation of `x`. So having in mind the complimentary code used for negative numbers(on **most compilers** by the way so this approach is not even very portable) -1 is represented by a sequence of 1-s and thus `~(-1)` will produce a zero.

Please don't use this approach. Simply write `scanf("%d", &n) != EOF` Way easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, And portable ways is `scanf("%d", &n) != EOF`, [-1 is value of EOF on most platform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan thanks! That is totally true. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Isn't `fscanf()` supposed to be the right choice to read from files as compared to `scanf()`?Can we read from anything other than `stdin` using `scanf()`?

Comment: @SheerFish in theory you can use `freopen` to redirect stdin but yes, scanf reads from `stdin`. The question is how to check for EOF in stdin as I understand it(see the code in the question).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I would never use the code in that question for EOF!!

Answer (score 2):

`~` is the bitwise NOT operator.  This is therefore a slightly obfuscated way of looping until `scanf` returns something other than -1.  In other words,

```
while(~scanf("%d",&n))
```

is equivalent to

```
while(scanf("%d",&n) != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In C ~ is an operator that performs a bit-wise shift operation it creates the complement of the original number.
And in C there isn't a boolean type, 0 is false everything else is true, in your example:

```
while(~scanf("%d",&n)) { 
  /* Your solution */
}
```

scanf() returns EOF if there's no more characters to read, which is equal to -1 (not in all platforms!) so -1 is represented by (111... 32 times in 32bit architecture) ~EOF = 0 thus there's a risk that you code don't work for all platforms.